# How to make the program give an error message when an incorrect ticker symbol is entered in a program that scrapes websites for stock data

Tags: python, url, web-scraping, python-requests

I am coding a project in which the user inputs the ticker of a stock, and then the program scrapes information about that stock from a specific website and returns the data. I have a fully working program, but an issue I have is that if the user enters a nonexistent stock ticker, the program gives an error and stops working. How can I fix this? Here is the relevant code segment for reference:

```
def make_url(ticker_symbol): #making a function that returns a URL when a ticker is passed through it
return "https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/%s:US" % ticker_symbol

def Calculation():
lower_stock = Ticker_entry.get()
stock = lower_stock.upper()
url = make_url(stock)
page = requests.get(url) #requesting the HTML code of the website
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "lxml") #Converting the HTML code of the website into a beautifulsoup object
```

How do I make it such that if the user enters a nonexistent stock, the program gives a message saying "Please enter a valid stock ticker."?

Here is the full code for reference:

```
import matplotlib
import sys
from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError
import matplotlib.dates as dates
from tkinter import *
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import lxml
import datetime
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

#Graphical User Interface
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
root = Tk()
root.title("Stock Price")
root.configure(background="white")

Calculator = Frame(root, height=300, width=700, bg="white").grid(column=0, row=2)
title = Label(root, bg="white", text="Stock Price Calculator", font="Sans 25 bold", fg="black").grid(row=0)

Stock_ticker = Label(root, text="Input stock ticker here:", font="Sans 18 bold")
Stock_ticker.place(x=7, y=60)
Ticker_entry = Entry(root, width=10)
Ticker_entry.place(x=235, y=64)

Stock_price = Label(root, text="Current stock price:", font="Sans 15")
Stock_price.place(x=7, y=100)

Stock_price_output = Entry(root, width=10)
Stock_price_output.place(x=160, y=100)

Stock_price_day = Label(root, text="Opening price for the day:", font="Sans 15")
Stock_price_day.place(x=7, y=140)

Stock_price_day_output = Entry(root, width=10)
Stock_price_day_output.place(x=195, y=141)

Last_closing_price = Label(root, text="Last closing price:", font="Sans 15")
Last_closing_price.place(x=7, y=180)

Last_closing_price_output = Entry(root, width=10)
Last_closing_price_output.place(x=180, y=181)

Stock_news = Label(root, text="News about stock:", font="Sans 15")
Stock_news.place(x=7, y=220)

Stock_news_output1 = Entry(root, width=50)
Stock_news_output1.place(x=150, y=221)

Stock_news_output2 = Entry(root, width=50)
Stock_news_output2.place(x=150, y=242)

Stock_news_output3 = Entry(root, width=50)
Stock_news_output3.place(x=150, y=263)

Submit = Button(root, text="Submit", font="Sans 14", command = lambda: Calculation())
Submit.place(x=165, y=300)

Reset = Button(root, text="Reset", font="Sans 14", command = lambda: Cleaning(Ticker_entry, Stock_price_output, Stock_price_day_output, Last_closing_price_output, Stock_news_output1, Stock_news_output2, Stock_news_output3))
Reset.place(x=250, y=300)
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

def make_url(ticker_symbol): #making a function that returns a URL when a ticker is passed through it
    return "https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/%s:US" % ticker_symbol

def make_historical_url(ticker_symbol):
    return "https://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/%s/historical" % ticker_symbol

def Calculation():
    lower_stock = Ticker_entry.get()
    stock = lower_stock.upper()
    url = make_url(stock)
    page = requests.get(url) #requesting the HTML code of the website
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "lxml") #Converting the HTML code of the website into a beautifulsoup object

    #Finding and inserting the current price
    current_number = soup.find('span', attrs={'class':'priceText__1853e8a5'})
    current_price = current_number.text
    Stock_price_output.insert(0, "$")
    Stock_price_output.insert(1, current_price)

    #Finding and inserting opening price
    opening_number = soup.find('div', attrs={'class':'value__b93f12ea'})
    opening_price = opening_number.text
    Stock_price_day_output.insert(0, "$")
    Stock_price_day_output.insert(1, opening_price)

    #Finding and inserting last closing price
    closing_numbers = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'value__b93f12ea'})
    closing_number = closing_numbers[1]
    closing_price = closing_number.text
    Last_closing_price_output.insert(0, "$")
    Last_closing_price_output.insert(1, closing_price)

    #Finding and inserting news
    news = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'headline__07dbac92'})
    news_1 = news[1].text
    news_2 = news[2].text
    news_3 = news[3].text

    Stock_news_output1.insert(0, news_1)
    Stock_news_output2.insert(0, news_2)
    Stock_news_output3.insert(0, news_3)

    #Drawing the graph of the stock
    historical_url = make_historical_url(stock)
    historical_page = requests.get(historical_url)
    soup_2 = BeautifulSoup(historical_page.content, "lxml")
    all_numbers = soup_2.find('tbody')
    all_nums = all_numbers.text
    all_nums_1 = all_nums.split()
    length = len(all_nums_1)

    prices = []
    dates = []

    current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    current_time_format = current_time.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
    all_nums_1[0] = current_time_format

    for t in range(int(length/6)):
        index = t * 6 + 4
        prices.append(all_nums_1[index])

    for t in range(int(length/6)):
        index = t * 6
        date_str = all_nums_1[index]
        format_str = '%m/%d/%Y'
        datetime_object = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_str, format_str)
        dates.append(datetime_object)

    final_dates = matplotlib.dates.date2num(dates)

    #plotting the graph of the last 3 months of stock price
    plt.plot_date(final_dates, prices, '-o')
    plt.xticks(rotation=90)
    plt.xlabel('Date')
    plt.ylabel('Price ($)')
    plt.suptitle("Price of the %s stock in the last 3 months" % stock)
    plt.show()

def Cleaning(writing_area1, writing_area2, writing_area3, writing_area4, writing_area5, writing_area6, writing_area7):
        writing_area1.delete(0, END)
        writing_area2.delete(0, END)
        writing_area3.delete(0, END)
        writing_area4.delete(0, END)
        writing_area5.delete(0, END)
        writing_area6.delete(0, END)
        writing_area7.delete(0, END)

root.mainloop()
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you thought about monitoring the status of the HTTP request? A valid ticker likely returns 200 (OK), whereas an invalid ticker would likely return 404 (Not Found).

Comment: @AdamMitchell Hi, thanks for the answer. I've unfortunately got no idea how to do that though. Could you kindly suggest a piece of code? Thanks a lot!

Comment: in your code `page = requests.get(url)` should return a status -  `page.status_code`

Comment: I've just had a play around and the status code route won't work as it'll just redirect to a handler page. However, the handler page has the text "The search for invalidTicker:US produced no matches". Thus, if that exact string appears in your BeautifulSoup object simply ask for a valid tickert.

Comment: @HamzaHaider How would I incorporate the 404 and 200 in that? Would it be like if page.status_code = 404? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @HamzaHaider I tried to print page.status_code, and the output seems to be 200 regardless of what ticker I enter. Any other suggestions?

Comment: the url you use is the following right `"https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/%s:US" % ticker_symbol` ? Ifthat's case im struggling to understand how it always replies back with status_code 200 regardless of stock ticker

Comment: @AdamMitchell Yeah, I got the same result too. How would I ask for a tickert? I tried to search for that specific string in the HTML code and then have the code quit if it found it, but it doesn't seem to be working. Do you have any code that I can try? Thanks so much for your help:)

Comment: @HamzaHaider That is the URL I am using, and it does replies back with 200 regardless of any input. Thanks!

Comment: Yh i've just tried it myself and you're right. In that case checking for `status_code == 200` wont help you here as Bloomberg always replies back with 200.

Comment: @AdamMitchell Thank you so much, it works perfectly!

Comment: No problem - could you please accept the answer so that it's more apparent to others that encounter the same issue? Thanks.

Comment: @AdamMitchell Hi, I'm kind of new to Stack Overflow so I realize there was such an option. Accepted now!

Comment: @LeonardoZapparoli No problem! If it really helped then an upvote would be even better ;) Anyways, glad I could be of assistance!

Comment: @AdamMitchell I did! But it doesn't show because I have less than 15 reputation points, I think.

Comment: @AdamMitchell Hi again, I also have another problem that I would really appreciate if you could help me with. The code you gave me works perfectly when the URL still does exist, but sometimes, for example, when I enter the stock ticker 'appl', it takes me to a page that says '404 Not Found'. Any ideas on how to resolve this? Thanks!

Comment: Hello. You can check response status code and see if it registers as 404, if not then you can just search the page using a similar method to what you’re already doing for the string “404 Not Found”.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I initially suggested monitoring HTTP status code, however this is a non-starter as Bloomberg will automatically redirect you to a simple page to state that a ticker is invalid. However, this page has a standardised message:

*The search for XYZ:US produced no matches. Try the symbol search.*

Thus, searching for a portion of that string will do the trick, don't even need to specifiy the exact ticker value:

```
import requests, lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/XYZ:US')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")

f = soup.find_all("div", "premium__message")

if 'produced no matches' in str(f):
    # do something
```